# How to store a value in an array without deleting the previous value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this method:

```
const [tableDataList, setTableDataList] = useState([]);

const getTableDataDetail = (value) => {
    let dataDetail = tableDataList;
    dataDetail = [...dataDetail, ...value]

    setTtableDataDetail(dataDetail);
};
```

This method is called every time I click a button But I want to keep the previous value and add the new value to the previous one..But what I have is that every time I click, the previous value is deleted.What should I do?

Comment: `const dataDetail = [ ...tableDataList, value ];`?

Comment: `setTtableDataDetail` (typo?) is different from `setTableDataList`. You need to call `setTableDataList` (I don't know what `setTtableDataDetail` is for).

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios.

If "value" is number then,

```
let dataDetail = [...tableDataList, value]
```

If "value" is array then,

```
let dataDetail = [...tableDataList, ...value]
```

The below code is worked for me.

For number:

```
const [tableDataList, setTableDataList] = React.useState([]);

const getTableDataDetail = (value) => {
let dataDetail = [...tableDataList, value]
setTableDataList(dataDetail);
};

<button onClick={() => getTableDataDetail(1)}>Click</button>
```

For Array:

```
const [tableDataList, setTableDataList] = React.useState([]);

const getTableDataDetail = (value) => {
let dataDetail = [...tableDataList, ...value]
setTableDataList(dataDetail);
};

<button onClick={() => getTableDataDetail([1,1])}>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [tableDataList, setTableDataList] = useState([]);

const getTableDataDetail = (value) => {
    setTtableDataDetail([ ...tableDataList, value ]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this to add to your state:

```
const [tableDataList, setTableDataList] = useState([]);

const getTableDataDetail = (value) => setTableDataList([...tableDataList, value])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
    const [tableDataList, setTableDataList] = useState([]);

const getTableDataDetail = (value) => {
    setTableDataList([...tableDataList, value]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a shallow copy of the state and then add new item to it:

```
const [tableDataList, setTableDataList] = useState([]);

const getTableDataDetail = (value) => {
    let copy = [...tableDataList];
    copy.push(value)
    setTtableDataDetail(copy);
};
```